# Latex error using bib file in IEEEtran document

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am trying to import my references into an IEEE style article. I use `.bib` file for saving my references. My code is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Conferences}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\Computer Engineering}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 abcd
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}
 something!
 I want to cite \cite{gamma}

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.

\section*{Acknowledgment}

The authors would like to thank...


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,adaptrefs}

\end{document}
```

The `.bib` file contains: (e.g.)

```
@article{gamma,
title = {Gamma, alpha, delta, and theta oscillations govern cognitive processes},
volume = {39},
issn = {0167-8760},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167876000001458},
doi = {10.1016/S0167-8760(00)00145-8},
abstract = { abs },
number = {2-3},
journal = {International Journal of Psychophysiology},
author = {Basar, Erol and {Basar-Eroglu}, Canan and Karakas, Sirel and Schürmann, Martin},
month = jan,
year = {2001},
keywords = {Alpha, Cognitive processing, Delta, Gamma oscillations, Sensory processing, Theta},
pages = {241--248},
file = {Basar et al. - 2001 - Gamma, alpha, delta, and theta oscillations govern.pdf:files/4/Basar et al. - 2001 - Gamma, alpha, delta, and theta oscillations govern.pdf:application/pdf;ScienceDirect Snapshot:files/5/S0167876000001458.html:text/html}
}
```

However I get errors:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}
>   Overfull \hbox (4.0748pt too wide) in paragraph

I just tested the `.bib` file with another article (with document style `article` and bibliography style `plain`) and it works well. Every other thing in the `.tex` file is correct since it can compile without these two reference lines. I tried `\bibliographystyle{plain}` also it doesn't work.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example.

Comment: Does it work with only the `.bib` file i.e. without the journal abbreviation list `\bibliography{adaptrefs}`?

Comment: No it doesn't! I can use the .bib file with normal article document class

Comment: The problem solved with commenting out the definition, compiling, and uncommenting them!